# Border Radius Not Working in a CSS Class

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a border radius to a button but when I use `border-radius: 5px;` in the CSS code below, nothing happens. Everything else works, its just that one keyword that doesn't. Everything I've read says that is how it should work, but it doesn't in the code below. I don't know if I'm just missing something below?

HTML:

```
 <button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Play</span></button>
```

CSS:

```
html {
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 background-image: url("/images/wallpaper.jpg"); 
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden; 
}

.heading {
 font-family: Sedgwick Ave Display;
 font-size: 70px;
 color: #cccc00;
}
.subH {
 font-family: Cinzel;
 font-size: 8px;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0.05px;
 left: 1190px;
 color: white;
}

.boxhead a {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.button {
  border-radius: 55px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 140px;
  left: 75px;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: Sedgwick Ave Display;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #cccc00;
  border: none; 
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
 }

.button span {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
 content: '\00bb';
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 top: 0;
 right: -20px;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
 opacity: 1;
 right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Try appending important to it. Like `border-radius: 5px; !important`. If this works, your original css is being overridden somewhere. You might need to open up the console and find conflicting css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .button {
>        border-radius: 5px; // This is what doesn't work

And this is *why* it doesn't work:

```
border-radius: 4px;
```

... which you have a couple of lines further down within the same rule, thereby *overwriting* the previous value.

Comment: It doesn't work even without the first border-radius: 5px;

Comment: What do you mean, without the first? You said _that_ was what wasn't working. If that's not it, then please go read how to create a [mcve], and edit your question, so that we can actually reproduce your problem.

Comment: You were correct by saying that there were two "border-radius" keywords, but even when I removed one of them from the code, there still wasn't a border radius on the button.

Comment: I copied this code into a new ASP.NET MVC project and the button has rounded borders so your code is working...must be something else outside the code you provided.

Comment: Then you perhaps have other CSS rules interfering, or other errors not apparent in the code snippets as shown alone. So, please go and create a proper example of the problem.

Comment: @CBroe I added the rest of the CSS code to the question.

Comment: Copy & paste of _that_: https://jsfiddle.net/5v5q8uxy/ - perfectly fine rounded corners.